# Random variables have equal moments

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have to show that if two random variables $X,Y$ are bounded and for all natural $n$ $EX^n=EY^n$ then they have the same distribution and the assumption that they are bounded is necessary.I've managed to show the second part by using logarithmic normal distribution but I'm struggling to show the first part, though it looks rther easy. I'd really appreciate a small hint rather than a full solution.Thanks for all answers.

Comment: I believe you can do something with characteristic functions or moment generating functions.

Comment: The assumption that they're bounded can be weakened but not dropped. $\qquad$

Comment: I agree with Jakob -- that is how I would solve the problem.